# How can one find this limit

Tags: real-analysis

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{\ln(2x+3)}{2e^{x+1}-2}$$
How can one calculate this Limit? without L' Hopital's rule

Comment: Use the fact that $\ln(x) < x$

Comment: The numerator is $\mathcal{O}(\ln(n))$, while the denominator is $\mathcal{O}(\exp(n))$.  Thus...

Comment: take a calculatro and you will check that tends to 0 :D because of the exponential below :D

Comment: @anorton: using this notation, you'd need to say the denominator is $\Omega(e^x)$, not $O(\cdot)$.

Comment: @ClementC. Eh.  How about $\Theta(\cdot)$ for both? :)  (Point taken... I learned asymptotics from CS, so I tend to misuse $\mathcal{O}(\cdot)$ notation.)

Answer (score 1):

Since $\ln(2x+3)\ll 2e^{x+1}-2$ as $x\to\infty$, you know the limit is zero.

Answer (score 1):

$e^t\ge 1+t$ for all $t\in\mathbb R$ shoul be well-known. It implies $e^t=(e^{t/2})^2\ge (1+\frac t2)^2=1+t+\frac{t^2}4>\frac14t^2$ for all $t\ge 0$. By taking the inverse function it also implies $\ln(1+t)\le t$ for all $t>-1$.

Answer (score 1):

When $x\nearrow\infty$, 
$$
\frac{\ln(2x+3)}{2e^{x+1}-2} = \frac{\ln x + \ln(2+3/x)}{e^{x}(2e-2e^{-x})} \sim \frac{\ln x}{2e e^x}
$$
Now, what can you say about the limit of $\frac{\ln x}{e^x}$?